# How to pivot pyspark dataframe rows to columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple pyspark dataframe like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|timestamp_local |timestamp_utc|device|key     |value|
-------------------------------------------------------
|2020-11-20      | 2020-11-20  | J3X  |Position| SEP |
|2020-11-20      | 2020-11-20  | J3X  |Soll    | 333 |
|2020-11-20      | 2020-11-20  | J3X  |Ist     | 444 |
|2020-11-21      | 2020-11-21  | J3X  |Position| SOP |
|2020-11-21      | 2020-11-21  | J3X  |Soll    | 100 |
|2020-11-21      | 2020-11-21  | J3X  |Ist     | 200 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to use pivot function but I am not sure if it's correct.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

result_df = raw_df.groupBy('timestamp_local', 'timestamp_utc', 'device').pivot('key').agg(f.first('value'))
```

Desired output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| timestamp_local|timestamp_utc|device|Position  | Soll | Ist 
---------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-11-20      | 2020-11-20  | J3X  | SEP      | 333  |  44
|2020-12-20      | 2020-12-20  | J3X  | SOP      | 100  |  200
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: your code works well, what's your problem?

Comment: the code is correct